# Rotate a triangle polygon according to mouse position?

Tags: java, rotation, mouse

I'm coding my own multi-player game in Java; I'm in need of help with rotating a triangle polygon according to the mouse position. I have this triangle, which represents the character, the player can click the right mouse button, and a bullet will fire from the top of the ship (which ever point I assign to be the top), but I want the rotation of the player(triangle), for aiming and such, to be controlled by the mouse and where it lies on the screen. How can I go about doing this, and I want to show an animation also of it rotating in respect to where the mouse is, not just appearing there.

Extra:
One more thing, after that, I'm most likely going to want to have the mouse locked to the screen, so that it won't trail off. How can I lock the mouse to the center of the screen?

I'm using the `drawPolygon` method from `java.awt.Graphics`, maybe this is the best way?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Also, how are you handling your Graphics?

Comment: Yep, we have no idea what GUI-graphics library you're currently using. I second the idea of creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Yes, it means a lot of extra work for you, but the benefits will be that we will be able to understand your problem to a much greater degree, improving your odds of getting a decent quick solution.